# How to solve set theory in wolfram alpha?

Tags: wolframalpha

A={1,2,3} B={1,2,3,4,5}, C={0,2,4,6} is 0 in (B union C)

How can I solve that does 0 is part of B union C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
intersection[{0},union[{1,2,3,4,5},{0,2,4,6}]]
```

gives you

```
{0}
```

and so zero is in that union while this

```
intersection[{8},union[{1,2,3,4,5},{0,2,4,6}]]
```

gives you

```
{}
```

and so 8 is not in that union.

[WA link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=intersection%5B%7B0%7D,union%5B%7B1,2,3,4,5%7D,%7B0,2,4,6%7D%5D%5D)

There may be other ways of accomplishing this with WA, but as always the question is how can you find a way to coax WA into understanding what you want it to do.

Comment: I didn't thought that I could resolve the way how you describe above. I got stuck that I need first define those sets and then try to proof is 0 part of B union C. Thanks for help!

Comment: @AnttiRuokanen It is often difficult to know what WolframAlpha will understand and what it will not. I tried this B={1,2,3,4,5}; C={0,2,4,6}; intersection[{0},union[B,C]] and was surprised when it understood that. I have had difficulty in the past getting WolframAlpha to understand assignments to variables, which is why I did not try to use assignments when I first tried to solve your problem. – Bill 25 mins ago